# skinning GUI in Qt 5+ , what options do i have?

Tags: qt5

i like to have the option to support skins in my application , which option do i have in Qt5+ 
to support skinning GUI ?
i found [this](http://qmmp.ylsoftware.com) that implemented some kind of skinning option ,
 i don't know if it good or not